# I need to check if a number is equal,2x,3x,4x,5x greater than the other. How can i do this?

Tags: java, if-statement, comparison, operators

Basically I just need this program to tell me that if a>b and by how much.So the conditions I need to check are if a==b, a>b,b<a and also I need to know how many times greater, which ranges from 2x,3x,4x,5x,6x.For example if the number is greater than 6 times just print "a lot bigger ".
If there is any other efficient way to do this then please give me suggestions.But the problem with this code is that it does not run fast the first condition of (a>b||a/b<1||a/b>0)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {



    Scanner input =new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("what is the value for a");
    double a =input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("what is the value for b");
    double b =input.nextDouble();


    if (a==b){
        System.out.println("a is equal to b");
    }
    else if (a>b||a/b<1||a/b>0){
        System.out.println("a is slightly bigger than b");

    }
    else if (a>b||a/b<3||a/b>=2) {
        System.out.println("a is 2x bigger than b");
    }
    else if (a>b||a/b<4||a/b>=3) {
        System.out.println("a is 3x bigger than b");
    }
    else if (a>b||a/b<5||a/b>=4) {
        System.out.println("a is 4x bigger than b");
    }

    else if (a>b||a/b<6||a/b>=5) {
        System.out.println("a is 5x bigger than b");
    }

    else if (a>b||a/b<100||a/b>6){
        System.out.println("a is alot bigger than b");
    }
    // to check if b is bigger than a
    else if (a<b||b/a<1||b/a>0){
        System.out.println("b is slightly bigger than a");

    }
    else if (a<b||b/a<3||b/a>=2) {
        System.out.println("b is 2x bigger than a");
    }
    else if (a<b||b/a<4||b/a>=3) {
        System.out.println("b is 3x bigger than a");
    }
    else if (a<b||b/a<5||b/a>=4) {
        System.out.println("b is 4x bigger than a");
    }

    else if (a<b||b/a<6||b/a>=5) {
        System.out.println("b is 5x bigger than a");
    }
```

// to check if its alot bigger

```
    else if (a>b||a/b<100||a/b>6){
        System.out.println("a is alot bigger than b");



    }



}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The second condition will always be true if a is greater than b, even if a is "a lot bigger than b". Are you sure you don't want && instead of || everywhere?

Also, consider adding another level of if statements like so (to reduce the amount of rules in the statements and increasing readability):

```
if (a == b) {
  // Code
} else if (a > b) {
  // If statements when a > b
} else {
  // If statements when b > a
}
```

Here's a solution that might work as an alternative:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("a: ");
    double a = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("b: ");
    double b = input.nextDouble();

    double greaterInt = (a > b) ? a : b;
    double smallerInt = (a > b) ? b : a;
    char greaterChar = (a > b) ? 'a' : 'b';
    char smallerChar = (a > b) ? 'b' : 'a';

    double frac = greaterInt / smallerInt;
    boolean noRemainder = 0 == greaterInt % smallerInt;

    String msg = "";

    if (noRemainder && frac <= 5) {
      if (frac == 1)
        msg = greaterChar + " and " + smallerChar + " are equal";
      else
        msg = greaterChar + " is " + (int) frac + "x bigger than " + smallerChar;
    } else if (frac < 2) {
      msg = greaterChar + " is slightly bigger than " + smallerChar;
    } else if (frac > 5) {
      msg = greaterChar + " is a lot bigger than " + smallerChar;
    } else {
      msg = "Nothing special to say about these numbers";
    }

    System.out.println(msg);
  }
}
```

Comment: wow i completely over looked that i meant to use the and operator thank you you are a genius now It should work fine

Comment: I've edited my post to give you an alternative to the code, that might be easier to read (not as many if statements with very similar conditions). @flowoverstack